# *Persistently* disable password authentication in SSHD on macOS

Tags: unix, ssh, macos, authentication

I want to be able to SSH in to my mac.

I do *not* want to be able to use passwords to authenticate.

I know how to configure this, what to put in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.  But every time I install even a minor OS version upgrade, I have to go make these changes again, and its failure mode is "fail dangerous" - it simply starts allowing password authentication again.

Is there some other way to tell the OS *not* to re-enable password authentication on every update?

Comment: Why “fail dangerous”? Surely requiring the password is the “safer” option... and “permanently” may be a better choice compared to “persistently”.

Comment: @SolarMike No, password is the least safe option. Requiring keys is the safe option here.

Comment: I can't test at the moment, but you may be able to specify a different (custom) config file with the `-f` flag.  In `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist` add in the '-f /path/to/custom_sshd_config.  This way, when an update is applied, it can't overwrite your settings reverting you back to password authentication.  See `man sshd_config` for more.

Comment: @Allan Isn‘t `/System/*` protected by SIP? And even if it isn‘t: wouldn’t an update overwrite the plist as well?

Comment: @nohillside - True.  There's also the possibility of *disabling* the system provided `sshd` and then creating a custom .plist (in /Library/LaunchDaemons) that will start `sshd` with the custom options.  An update shouldn't over write it if done that way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think starting with macOS Monterey (12.x) you can add your changes for `sshd_config` to a file in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf`.

I could not find documentation for this on macOS, but for example, on Ubuntu 20.04 the `sshd_config` manpage explains how this works.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! The "documentation", such as it is, is in a big comment above the line `Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` .  I'll set up my sshd configuration on a Monterey machine and see if it gets blown away when the next update comes out...

Comment: Were your sshd configuration changes preserved between updates using this approach?

Comment: @Bob Bah, sorry, I forgot to set this up so I'm not sure.  I just wrote a file in that directory with `ChallengeResponseAuthentication no` and `PasswordAuthentication no` and it has taken effect, but I'll let you know after the next system update.

Comment: Hooray a system update happened today. As soon as Xcode finishes updating, I can finally validate this…

Comment: At long last. Update from `21D62` to `21E230` applied. And yes… it worked! Passwords still aren't accepted, only public keys! Answer now accepted. Thank you @rjs!

Comment: Several updates later (12.4, `21F79`) this is still working. Hooray!